# Mocked Interface with NSubstitute on F# does not allow Returns

Tags: f#, c#-to-f#, nsubstitute

I have the following code:

```ml
open NSubstitute
type MyClass()=
    let myObject = Substitute.For<IMyInterface>()
    do myObject.MyProperty.Returns(true)
    do myObject.MyMethod().Returns(true)
```

On "Returns" (both) I get the error that is not defined. The equivalent C# code works without issue. Adding `|> ignore` at the end of the do lines does not help. Am I missing something there?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So after I tried the code (Mark Seemann's, as to avoid my C# class) on VS2012, fsi, through direct compilation with fsc and on VS2013, the issue is clearly a VS2012 problem. The code works correctly with the other three.

Not sure yet if it is using a different version of F#. Will need further investigation. But at least, for now, on VS2012 I can use:

```ml
do SubstituteExtensions.Returns(myObject.MyProperty, true) |> ignore
```

It works as well when I need to pass parameters to methods.

Answer (score 1):

I know you wrote that adding `|> ignore` at the end doesn't help, but this compiles on my machine:

```
type IMyInterface =
    abstract MyProperty : bool with get, set
    abstract member MyMethod : unit -> bool

open NSubstitute

type MyClass() =
    let myObject = Substitute.For<IMyInterface>()
    do myObject.MyProperty.Returns(true) |> ignore
    do myObject.MyMethod().Returns(true) |> ignore
```

I attempted to infer the definition of `IMyInterface` from the question; did I get it wrong?

Comment: IMyInterface is a C# class on my code. I tried on a completely new project and copy the code that you have here, and still gives me the same error.

Comment: So maybe the error is something environmental on my VS installation.